# Image Optimization like TinyPNG

Tags: image, optimization, image-optimization

I have searched for a good Mass Image Optimizer over Google to use on Windows or by PHP to optimize the Images of a Folder but none of them where so good like TinyPNG. Most of them raised the size instead to shrink. Google Pagespeed Insight likes the Sizes of TinyPNG but nothing compareable found.

Any advice I can use?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

TinyPNG uses this library: http://pngquant.org/

Available on Windows, Linux and Mac.

Comment: Any idea what they are using for JPG?

Comment: Source: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4167964 & https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6803187

Answer (score 9):

Google PageSpeed Insights recommends two: [OPTIPNG](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/) and [PNGOUT](http://advsys.net/ken/utils.htm).
You can use them together (one by one) on the same image, often it gives a better results.

Comment: Google's algorithm ultimately requires the use of very low quality of JPEG. It's no problem to do with any editor, but JPEG compression is lossy and so the image often become just unsuitable. I trick it by converting JPEGs to PNGs with further optimization. PNG compression is loseless, so it cannot harm the image. It's ridiculous, but from Google's point of view large, but optimized PNG is better than smaller JPEG.
BTW, if you found my answer helpful please accept it :)

Comment: Well my Problem is that I handle right now with over 4500 JPEG Images. The CMS does only accept JPEG Files and thats why I am looking for a solution for it. The best compression and quality I have found is TINYJPG.com but it is not OpenSource.

Comment: you can try http://optimizejpeg.com/ it allows 50 images  jpg ,gif  & png and limit is also more 500 images agaisnt 20 by tiny.quality is comparable